# Video recording bug fix for CM9 ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, camera, bugs, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have a Galaxy Mini(GT-S 5570). I recently upgraded it from Gingerbread 2.3.6 to ICS(CM9). Now everything is working fine except for the video recording. The camera takes pictures without any issues but the video recording does not work. I followed the procedures stated in this website for installation. http://www.techgeekal.com/2012/10/27/cyanogenmod-9-stable-27102012-for-galaxy-minipop-gt-s5570/ Is there a bug fix for the video recording? Thanks in advance for looking into this question! :)

Comment: Have you checked with the [CyanogenMod Forum](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/)? That would be the first address for CM bugfix information I'd say. Here's a helpful [Google Search Link](http://www.google.com/search?q=video+recording+bug+site%3Acyanogenmod.org&oq=video+recording+bug+site%3Acyanogenmod.org) for that to check while waiting for an answer :)